# kendo grid losing sequence

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm developing one web project in `MVC`, we're using `Kendo UI` controls.

I'm facing some issue in `KendoGrid`.
In one of the page, KendoGrid loading around 80 columns where, 40 of them are being loaded dynamically.

```
columns.Bound(o => o.Altered).Visible(false);
columns.Bound(o => o.col1).Width(150);
columns.Bound(o => o.col2).Width(150);
columns.Bound(o => o.col3).Width(150);
.
.
.
.
.
 foreach (myModel myObjet in Model.ModelCollection)
 {
     columns.Bound(typeof(string), string.Format("O{0}", myObjet.ObjectNumber)).Width(100).Title(myObjet.ObjectDescription).HtmlAttributes(new { title = myObjet.ObjectDescription + " : #= O1 #" });
     columns.Bound(typeof(string), string.Format("ObjectName{0}", myObjet.ObjectNumber)).Width(100);
 }
```

It's loading columns and rows correctly, but the problem is it's losing its
sequence. What I mean is, it's not rendering the column the way I've
mentioned here.

Comment: Which columns are not in the correct sequence? All 80 columns, just the static ones, or just the dynamic ones?

Comment: @digawp, 40 dynamic columns, if you see above code, Im adding dynamic columns at very last, but when its being rendered, its sequence is something like  s1,s2,s3...s17,d1,d2,d3..d16,s18,s19,s20...s40...d19...d40  
***s = Static Column***  <br/>  
***d = dynamic column***

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to sort it before?

```
foreach (myModel myObjet in Model.ModelCollection.OrderBy(f => f.ObjectNumber))
 {
     columns.Bound(typeof(string), string.Format("O{0}", myObjet.ObjectNumber)).Width(100).Title(myObjet.ObjectDescription).HtmlAttributes(new { title = myObjet.ObjectDescription + " : #= O1 #" });
     columns.Bound(typeof(string), string.Format("ObjectName{0}", myObjet.ObjectNumber)).Width(100);
 }
```

Comment: What is the type of ObjectNumber?